# NSURL always nil

Tags: ios, xcode

I have weird problem and just can understand it

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *mylink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Bermad/IR_World/CaseStudy/%@",documentsPath,link];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:mylink];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[WebView loadRequest:request];
```

link is populated, my link is also populated but targetURL is nil, why?
[image]

Comment: I'd say it's because of the ", " at the end of the URL. You need to escape them.

Comment: I could see a comma before Portugal...

Comment: NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:[mylink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; instead of using NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:mylink];

Comment: instead of "NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:mylink];"  use "NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mylink];"